# Prevent screen shot after closing the application

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem that recognized recently but could not find the solution.Generally when we run an application in simulator we get the following folders:documents,library,tmp,etc.Now if I close the application suddenly in simulator then in library folder we can find caches folder and in that snapshot folder.In this folder we get one folder with bundle identifier name and in that we get screen shot of the application where we closed it.Now my requirement is to stop those screen shots when I close application

Comment: Possibly you could scramble the screen just before going to background. Or simply put a scrambled view over whole window.

Comment: but I need to stop without occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide your view in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

This is standard behaviour, as it gives the impression that the app resumes quicker if it appears to go back to where it left off - even if technically the app is not quire responsive yet. All you need to do is put something else on the screen in the above method and this will now become the first thing that comes to the front when a user opens your app back up

Comment: U gave clear idea what rokjarc commented.This works fine.But I need that screen shot should be occurred and that action should be prevented.

Comment: You can't prevent it it is built in, you have to work with the framework and just cover sensitive info